# Order(but not sort) a python dict according to required format

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I know this is a very basic python concept, but felt like it will be useful to someone.

I have the following list

```
list_items = [
 ('name','Random'),
 ('type','Film'),
 ('description','Nothing'),
 ('rent_active','True'),
 ('rent_price_usd','23.4'),
 ('rent_price_episode_usd','23.4'),
 ('buy_episode_active','23.4'),
```

]

Now i want to convert it to dict, so we can do `dict(list_items)` and the result would be

```
{'buy_episode_active': '23.4',
 'description': 'Nothing',
 'name': 'Random',
 'rent_active': 'True',
 'rent_price_episode_usd': '23.4',
 'rent_price_usd': '23.4',
 'type': 'Film'}
```

But what i need is the items in the dictionary should be in the same order as the items in the above list(`list_items`) as below

```
{
 'name': 'Random',
 'type': 'Film'
 'description': 'Nothing',
 'rent_active': 'True',
 'rent_price_usd': '23.4',
 'rent_price_episode_usd': '23.4',
 'buy_episode_active': '23.4',
 }
```

I know a list a ordered collection of elements and dictionary is unordered collection of elements, but still i need the dict in the above required format, i am ok if we do extra processing on the list or processing takes time. So can anyone please let me know how to order the dict according to our required format ?

Comment: *"still i need the dict in the above required format"*  -why?

Comment: well, someone needs the dict readable according to this format

Comment: ...why? If readability is important, is a dictionary the best tool? Could you write a function to *display* a dictionary with a defined key order? Without understanding your problem, it's difficult to optimally solve it.

Answer (score 7):

[collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) does what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
>>> list_items = [
...  ('name','Random'),
...  ('type','Film'),
...  ('description','Nothing'),
...  ('rent_active','True'),
...  ('rent_price_usd','23.4'),
...  ('rent_price_episode_usd','23.4'),
...  ('buy_episode_active','23.4'),
... ]
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mydict = OrderedDict(list_items)
>>> mydict
OrderedDict([('name', 'Random'), ('type', 'Film'), ('description', 'Nothing'), ('rent_active', 'True'), ('rent_price_usd', '23.4'), ('rent_price_episode_usd', '23.4'), ('buy_episode_active', '23.4')])
```

Note that OrderedDict was introduced into the standard library in python 2.7.  If you have an older version of python, you can find recipes for ordered dictionaries on [ActiveState](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576693-ordered-dictionary-for-py24/)